# MVC Successful Form Submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a `Html.BeginForm` in my MVC Application. When the user clicks the Submit button, and if all is good, I wish to send the user to a specific View. Can anyone kindly tell me how I can make the user go to a View that's already defined (and a solution to directing the user to a View that's outside of the current Controller).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RedirectToAction() to redirect user to other action and controller.

After that you verify model state, call

```
Return RedirectToAction("Index","Home")
```

to redirect to 'Home' controller and 'Index' action. You can pass additional parameters also.

Comment: Can you kindly explain Model State? Is that regarding if all of the data has been entered in the form?

Comment: Yes. Im using in my action something like: if modelstate.isvalid then do some action with database and when everything is ok (good username and password) then 'return redirecttoaction'. If user posted data isnt valid you can show message to user or make other redirect.